# Real time disabling widgets in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have two radio buttons. When clicking one of them it should disable some widgets and activate some other. What should I do for that?

e.g If I check `radioButton1` then it should disable a lineEdit instantly and if I check `radioButton2` it should enable the first line edit and disable lineEdit2.

All this in real time.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? (show us the code if you can) What is it you're stuck on? In its current form this is not really a great question to be honest.

Comment: I suggest reading the getting started docs for Qt and use creator which has code completion and built in help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without having much to go on at the moment, a general answer would be the following:

Handle the appropriate signal of your radio buttons. Using this signal you can trigger a method/loop where you set your widgets to be disabled using [`setEnabled(false)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).

Given your situation you could have something similar to the following two methods, which you call depending on the signals you receive:

```
void OnRadioButton1()
{
    lineEdit->setEnabled(false);
    lineEdit2->setEnabled(true);
}

void OnRadioButton2()
{
    lineEdit->setEnabled(true);
    lineEdit2->setEnabled(false);
}
```

It's pretty straight-forward really. I don't understand where this whole notion of "real-time" comes into play. It's a single response to a single input "event".

Of course, this could just as well be a single method with a specific (boolean) argument or whatever. But given that we're discussing a hypothetical example case here that does not necessarily reflect your real code, this should at least provide you with a bit of an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking of creating an infinite loop but it will consume lots of CPU which is unfavourable, any other way?
Secondly I tried setEnabled(false) for a combo box and i got this `error: no matching function for call to 'QComboBox::isEnabled(bool)` and same for lineEdit widget. What am I doing wrong

Comment: I said `setEnabled(false)`. Your error indicates `isEnabled(bool)`. That function does exist, but without the boolean argument, and only indicates whether or not something is enabled. It does not set it to be. So you might want to correct that. And why the infinite loop? I don't see how that figures in at all. You might want to show us your code. So update your question.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. But actually i cannot share the code because it is around 1200 lines cpp, many resources and forms. I am working on a toolkit for Android Phones. Can you pls suggest how should I implement it? so that it handles the widgets in a real time?

Comment: I can't really suggest anything more than I already have, with the information you've given us. If you can't narrow it down to a simple illustrative example (not 1200 lines ;) ) then there's not a whole lot I can do.

Comment: Sorry I updated my post with more details but I cannot share the code for some reasons :(. Can you pls give me a example code for my prob?